# Is it good approach to use Mocking for integration tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I'm currently learning unit tests and integration tests. In my unit tests I have been using Mockito for mocking, such as when(something).thenReturn(something) etc. I used this approach to test the business logic of the application.

Now I am trying to create integration tests to test all the endpoints of my application. The layers of my application are as follows: Controller -> Interface -> Service -> Repository.

When I tried to create an integration test for the POST method that creates a user, the request should have returned the created user, but returned an empty string. The test looked like this:

```
@Test
  void create() throws Exception {
    UserCreationDTO user = new UserCreationDTO(1L, "Steve", "steve@mail.com", "password");

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String text = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);

    this.mockMvc
        .perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/users").contentType("application/json").content(text))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.id").value(1))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.name").value("Steve"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.email").value("steve@mail.com"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.password").value("password"));
}
```

I later found out that I need to add a line of code to mock the userInterface and what it should return.

```
Mockito.when(userInterface.create(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(user);
```

After adding it, the method started returning the created user and the test passed. After reading a couple of articles, I came across an approach that says an **integration test should not contain mocking.**

**So my question is:** Is this approach I have taken correct and can it be considered a correct integration test or do I need to get rid of the mocking of userInterface? In case I have to remove the mocking, how can I ensure that the test passes and returns not just an empty string, but an actually created user?

Comment: "integration" always comes with a "scope"...so, when you want to test the integration `Web -> Controller -> Interface`, then mocking at that place is "ok"/"must". (and you can still call it integration test) but when you want to "integration test" all of `Web -> ... -> DB`, then you should not use mocks, but real instances.

Comment: So if I dont want to test evrything `Web -> ... -> DB`, but only the controller and its endpoints, I can just verify (`verify(interface).method()`) if the endpoint calls the right method from interface?

Comment: Exactly (just a matter of perspective/scope) but since it is easy&"cheap"(er than mocking!?), Why not `...-> DB`?;)

Comment: I had use cases where I had to connect with external third party systems over vpn to execute full api endpoint. In this case, I do not wish to fail my build due to reasons like socket timeout, also these integrations can go down anytime. So there I used mocks
else I agree with @xerx593, scope of test matters.

Comment: Since my app is not using any 3rd party systems or anything and its just a few endpoints, I will just stick with the idea of verifying if the endpoint calls the right method in the interface. Thank you very much for the answer :)